# Any Suggestions for Log4Net Configuration Gui?

Tags: user-interface, configuration, log4net

Does anyone have any suggestions for a Gui for editing the log4net config files.  We have people in the field who need to be able to increase, decrease, or specialize logging but don't have the background to mess in the XML.

Comment: they can't edit a well commented xml file?

Comment: dotjoe: you must be confusing developers with users.  A common error I often make myself.

Answer (score 3):

I used this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Log4netEditor.aspx a few years ago to provide a simple GUI to log4net. I haven't used it recently so I don't know if it's still working with recent releases of log4net.

Comment: Thanks. I had looked at that, but it didn't really simplify things any more than the XML.  It just covered the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard to make a simple .NET Winforms app that can read a .xml file and allow the user to edit it. As it will only be used by users with specific needs you can just put in the necessary drop-down menus, ticks boxes or edit boxes to allow then to change the values needed.

You can then do some basic error/range checking to make sure they can't enter invalid values.